# select command for foreign key within same table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Hi guys i have this given table..in which i want to have a select query to replace managerid with the name of the employee with which it is associated.

For example: i want output as

1 | andy | sw  |andy

2  | brij  | sw  |andy

3 | toby | sw  |brij

[image]

Is it possible to do this within same table .

Comment: yes it is possible, you can try join with alias on the same table

Comment: try this <br> `select e.empid,e.empname,e.designation,m.manager from tblEmployee as e JOIN tblManager as m ON e.ManagerID=m.ManagerID GROUP BY e.empid,e.empname,e.designation,m.manager`

Comment: tried this..still didnt get the output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from @Shakeer's answer,i found one more alternative.This one is without left join..but a self join.

```
SELECT e.empid, e.empname, m.empname  "Manager" FROM test_Emp e, test_Emp m WHERE e.managerid=m.empid;
```

Comment: Without `LEFT JOIN` it does not include the manager who does not have any `MANAGERID`

Answer (score 1):

Just do self Join to know the Manager name.

```
SELECT E1.EMPNAME, E1.DESIGNATION, E2.EMPNAME AS MANAGER_NME
FROM EMPLOYEE E1
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE E2 ON E1.MANAGER_ID = E2.EMPID
```

Comment: just a little correction replace EMPID with E2. EMPID in the last...then it runs perfectly

Comment: Yes.. Sorry for typo mistake @BhawnaJain

Answer (score 1):

Also try this way:

```
 SELECT EMPID,EMPNAME,DESIGNATION, case when 'MANAGERID' <> EMPNAME then EMPNAME else null end as MANAGERID FROM YOURTABLE
```

Comment: Got following errors:1.Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'2.Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: My mistake, i guess you are using MYSQL. Updated the answer for SQL.

Comment: Thanks for appreciating.

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be

```
SELECT
  a.EMPID,
  a.EMPNAME,
  a.DESIGNATION,
  (Select b.EMPNAME from Employee as b where a.MANAGERID = b.EMPID) as    
  MANAGER
  FROM
  Employee as a
```

Comment: one more way to solve this problem ..upvotted ur answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SELF_JOIN in the case when you want to fetch records from same table.

For example:

Table Name: employee

Fields : EMPID , EMPNAME , MANAGERID

Now if you want to get the details of Empolyees who are in Manager Position for that we need to write query like this:

```
    select e2.EMPID,e2.EMPNAME, COALESCE(e1.EMPNAME,e2.EMPNAME,e1.EMPNAME) as Mannager
from `employee` e1 right join `employee` e2
on e1.empid=e2.managerid
```

Comment: No Shoukat...please read the question first..ur query equivalents 'select empid,empname from employee'..

Comment: sorry ...... try this one "select e2.EMPID,e2.EMPNAME, COALESCE(e1.EMPNAME,e2.EMPNAME,e1.EMPNAME) as Mannager
from `employee` e1 right join `employee` e2
on e1.empid=e2.managerid"

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Emp table (EmpID INT,EmpName varchar(100),Designation varchar(10),MgrID INT)

INSERT INTO @Emp(EmpID,EMpName,Designation,MgrID)
SELECT *
FROM ( VALUES(1,'andy','sw',NULL),
             (2,'brij','sw',1),
             (3,'toby','sw',2)
)v (EmpID,EMpName,Designation,MgrID)

SELECt e.EmpID,e.EMpName,e.Designation,ISNULL(e1.EmpName,e.EmpName) AS Mgr 
FROM @Emp e
LEFT JOIN @Emp e1 ON e.MgrID = e1.EmpID
```

Comment: i guess third one is for editing..But that doent produce desired results...it is showing extra two colums in the end...and andy column is missing...So downvote from me

Answer (score 0):

```
    select e2.EMPID,e2.EMPNAME, COALESCE(e1.EMPNAME,e2.EMPNAME,e1.EMPNAME) as Mannager
from `employee` e1 right join `employee` e2
on e1.empid=e2.managerid
```

Output :.[image]